# Is there a better way to grab part of line (which isnt consistent) using sed and append it to the end?

Tags: sed

I want to grab a string and append it to the end of the line. Issue is, the pattern isn't consistent. I also want to keep the whole line intact, just copy part of it and append it to the end separating by semi colon.
I have searched similar questions but they don't exactly answer what i am trying to do.

This is the example file with 1000s of lines (input):

```
Group: ch.qos.lback Name: lback.sa Version: 0.1.11 
Manifest Project URL: http://www.xx.x
Manifest license URL: http://www.xx.x/l.html
SUM License: Abra Nabra License - v 3.0 \- http://www.xx.x/l.html
SUM License: GNU Lesser General Public License \- http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lhtml

Group: com.aol.sim Name: cycact Version: 3.0.0-RT 
SUM Project URL: https://xx.com/xx
SUM License: The Apache Software License, Version 2.0 \- http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt

Group: com.fa Name: ce Version: 1.3.4 
SUM License: The Apache Software License, Version 2.0 \- http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Embedded license: cle-1.3.4.jar/META-INF/LICENSE cle-1.3.4.jar/META-INF/NOTICE
```

What i would like is desired output:

```
Group: ch.qos.lback Name: lback.sa Version: 0.1.11 
Manifest Project URL: http://www.xx.x
Manifest license URL: http://www.xx.x/l.html
SUM License: Abra Nabra License - v 3.0 \- http://www.xx.x/l.html;Abra Nabra License - v 3.0
SUM License: GNU Lesser General Public License \- http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lhtml;GNU Lesser General Public License

Group: com.aol.sim Name: cycact Version: 3.0.0-RT 
SUM Project URL: https://xx.com/xx
SUM License: The MIT License, Version 2.0 \- http://www.x.x.txt;The MIT License, Version 2.0

Group: com.fa Name: ce Version: 1.3.4 
SUM License: The Apache Software License, Version 2.0 \- http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt;The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
Embedded license: cle-1.3.4.jar/META-INF/LICENSE cle-1.3.4.jar/META-INF/NOTICE
```

so basically extract the name of the license and append it to the end.

```
e.g. ;Abra Nabra License - v 3.0
```

I can do the following to grab string in between and store it in a variable:

```
var=$(echo "SUM License: Apache License, Version 2.0 \- http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0" | gsed -n 's/.*\SUM License: \(.*\)\http.*/\1/p')
```

and then add it to the end of the file doing another sed with while loop:

```
gsed "/^SUM License:/ s/$/;$var;/"
```

is there a better way to do this?
where i can copy and append without messing around much?

Comment: `sed 's/^SUM License: *\([^\]*\).*/&;\1/'`? See https://ideone.com/Oo8Msx

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! this works! Can you write it as an answer so i can mark it?

Comment: `awk '{printf "%s%s\n", $0, $1 ~ /SUM License/ ? $2 : ""}' FS='[:\\\\]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match any chars other than `/` after `SUM License:` and capture them into Group 1 while matching the rest of the line, then use `&;\1`  in the replacement pattern to append the captured name after a semi-colon at the end of the line where the match occurred:

```
sed 's/^SUM License: *\([^\]*\).*/&;\1/'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/Oo8Msx).

**POSIX BRE pattern details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `SUM License:` - a literal string
- `*` - 0 or more spaces
- `\([^\]*\)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `\`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

**RHS details**

- `&` - the whole match value
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\1` - the Group 1 value placeholder.

Answer (score -1):

So looking at the line

```
SUM License: Abra Nabra License - v 3.0 \- http://www.xx.x/l.html
```

Does it always start with `SUM License:`? Does it always end the licence with `\- http://`?

If so you could use that as your sed rule, emitting the original line contents first?

```
s/^(SUM License: )(.*)( \- http:)(.*)$/\1\2\3\4;\2/
```

Does your sed support \0? Then it becomes:

```
s/^(SUM License: )(.*)( \- http:)(.*)$/\0;\2/
```

You could also drop the excess brackets.

Note that these are readable extended regexp, introduced with option `-r`. If you want to use traditional regexp you will have to backslash all the brackets.